# how to reform my HTML in Android

Tags: android, json

I have data in server.and i am retrieving them as JSON data as the android gets data usually from the server side.
but these are all raw HTMLs. how do I put them as the html pages are shown.
like I am trying to retrieve some news who are getting posted as JSON in my website.

And I am showing them in a text view.
I need to show them in my android as the real data.how is it done in Android?
if you want to check http://hadid.aero/news_and_json this is the link from where I am getting the JSONs,
I am getting the data correctly that's not a problem but the problem is to show them in a good form.p
please suggest me how to do it?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand the issue but from what I see it can be one of 2:

1. if you get HTML and you need to show it nicely, try using [`html.fromHtml`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html)
2. if you're getting the wrong information from your server i.e. you're expecting JSON but getting HTML, this is your server's issue and yo need to fix it there.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using Textview u can use WebView. Like:

```
//add WebView in xml file, and in onCreate() set like below

String customHtml="ur html data as a string";
WebView webview=(WebView)findViewByID("view id");
webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```